# neo4j 4.0 testing with embedded database DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder is found nowhere

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I'm a beginner in neo4j. I'm trying to build tests using embedded neo4j database inside a springboot application. I haven't succeeded since the class DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder is found nowhere Please note I'm using version 4.0.2 Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full classname is [org.neo4j.dbms.api.DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/4.0/community/neo4j/src/main/java/org/neo4j/dbms/api/DatabaseManagementServiceBuilder.java).

Here is a [sample class](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-documentation/blob/4.0/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java) that uses the builder.

Comment: Hi @cybersam, thank you. I've already found that class. Thank you for the sampe which I'll use for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with using an embedded neo4j db for my tests a few months back as well.

In case you don't find a suitable solution for the embedded version, I ended up starting a real instance of the db...

I adjusted a bit neo4j's official Dockerfile to use jdk instead of jre and was able to run my tests against it.

Here's the Dockerfile, starting from the official [3.4.5-enterprise Dockerfile](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/a097f1663938dc56b81ae88f1cf7caba0b40004c/3.4.5/enterprise/Dockerfile):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        make && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD maven-settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml

# from official neo4j:3.4.5-enterprise image content (changed base image to use jdk instead of jre)
RUN addgroup --system neo4j && adduser --system --no-create-home --home /var/lib/neo4j --ingroup neo4j neo4j

ENV NEO4J_SHA256=0629f17a99ba90d6900c98f332c775a732cc2ad6298b8df41a2872277b19e6e3 \
    NEO4J_TARBALL=neo4j-enterprise-3.4.5-unix.tar.gz \
    NEO4J_EDITION=enterprise \
    NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
    TINI_VERSION="v0.18.0" \
    TINI_SHA256="12d20136605531b09a2c2dac02ccee85e1b874eb322ef6baf7561cd93f93c855"

ARG NEO4J_URI=http://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-enterprise-3.4.5-unix.tar.gz

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y \
    bash \
    curl \
    && curl -L --fail --silent --show-error "https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini" > /sbin/tini \
    && echo "${TINI_SHA256}  /sbin/tini" | sha256sum -c --strict --quiet \
    && chmod +x /sbin/tini \
    && curl --fail --silent --show-error --location --remote-name ${NEO4J_URI} \
    && echo "${NEO4J_SHA256}  ${NEO4J_TARBALL}" | sha256sum -c --strict --quiet \
    && tar --extract --file ${NEO4J_TARBALL} --directory /var/lib \
    && mv /var/lib/neo4j-* /var/lib/neo4j \
    && rm ${NEO4J_TARBALL} \
    && mv /var/lib/neo4j/data /data \
    && chown -R neo4j:neo4j /data \
    && chmod -R 777 /data \
    && chown -R neo4j:neo4j /var/lib/neo4j \
    && chmod -R 777 /var/lib/neo4j \
    && ln -s /data /var/lib/neo4j/data

# Install latest su-exec
RUN  set -ex; \
     \
     curl -o /usr/local/bin/su-exec.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ncopa/su-exec/master/su-exec.c; \
     \
     fetch_deps='gcc libc-dev'; \
     apt-get update; \
     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $fetch_deps; \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
     gcc -Wall \
         /usr/local/bin/su-exec.c -o/usr/local/bin/su-exec; \
     chown root:root /usr/local/bin/su-exec; \
     chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/su-exec; \
     rm /usr/local/bin/su-exec.c; \
     \
     apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $fetch_deps

ENV PATH /var/lib/neo4j/bin:$PATH

ARG NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/neo4jtest
ENV NEO4J_AUTH=${NEO4J_AUTH}

WORKDIR /var/lib/neo4j

VOLUME /data

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 7474 7473 7687

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "-g", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["neo4j"]
```

I used [the original `docker-entrypoint.sh` script](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j-publish/blob/a097f1663938dc56b81ae88f1cf7caba0b40004c/3.4.5/enterprise/docker-entrypoint.sh).